# Duplicação de Registros Ajax, JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho uma página HTML para confirmar itens de uma transferência de mercadorias.

Nela, é utilizado jQuery, AJAX com a opção `async: false` e VRaptor.

Fiz o seguinte teste:

- Criei uma transferência com vários itens.
- Após transferir, acessei a tela de confirmação para confirmar o recebimento dos itens.
- Confirmei todos eles e cliquei no botão finalizar. Este botão dispara o evento que varre a tela e manda os parâmetros dos itens confirmados (como por exemplo chaves PK), passando para o servidor que fará a persistência dos dados.

O processo funciona corretamente, quando um usuário está logado, utilizando um navegador.

O problema acontece quando o usuário logado resolve utilizar dois navegadores e clica no botão 'finalizar' nos dois navegadores. Isso gera, no banco, uma duplicação de registros.

Como eu poderia resolver o problema, já que não posso ter um lock para o mesmo usuário e, se o mesmo utilizar dois navegadores (iguais ou não), impedir que se duplique registros no banco de dados?

Comment: nao existe um registro unico que voce possa verificar antes de inserir?

Comment: Cara, não é uma boa prática usar o ajax deste modo. Pode bugar alguma coisa e travar o navegador. 
Mas não entendi uma coisa, se o usuário usa 2 navegadores, preenche 2 vezes, o certo é gerar 2 registros mesmo não é?

Comment: @rafaelphp No momento em que é clicado no botão finalizar o java tem a função de inserir os registros no banco de dados. Isso é feito um a um e caso tente adicionar o mesmo registro o método não é executado. O problema acontece quando é utilizado dois navegadores logados pelo mesmo usuário. O método é disparado duas vezes por duas Threads. O que eu poderia fazer para que execute um processo somente após ter concluído o primeiro, sendo que já estou usando isso no async : false do ajax;

Comment: poste o código, assim fica muito difícil poder dizer o que pode estar ocorrendo, tem chances de ser negativado.

Comment: Olha, se não pode haver registros com colunas iguais no BD, porque esses campos não geram uma chave surrogate (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)?

Comment: Sua solução depende de `n` variáveis. O sistema é utilizado por mais de um usuário? Vários usuários podem inserir registros ao mesmo tempo? Um usuário pode inserir múltiplos registros iguais em outras circunstâncias que não a citada acima?

Comment: Penso que esta pergunta é mais relevante no lado do servidor do que no lado do cliente... Que linguagem usa no lado do servidor?

Comment: Obrigado por todas as respostas. Verificarei a possibilidade de cada uma delas

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser duas situações:

1 - quando o usuario clicar no botao, implemente no evento click o hide do botao para evitar que ele seja clicado 2 vezes.

2 - use o stopPropagation() no evento para evitar replicação do evento entre as tags

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score -4):

Pode ser porque você esta chamando seu Js duas vezes.
Aconteceu comigo estava chamando no Header e no Footer o mesmo js.
De uma conferida